# Shorter word for 'Settings'

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am creating an application which has a button which opens the settings pane, but there is just not quite enough space on the screen for the whole word (in a readable font size). Is there a shorter word that means the same? Something like "properties" except, well, shorter. Thanks!

Comment: A picture of a cog or gear is often used for this purpose or alternatively a wrench/spanner. I posted this in the comments because this isn't really a EL&U answer.

Comment: That's a good idea, I think that might be the long-term solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt you can do any better than *Setup*, or possibly *Specs* or *Prefs* if you use cutoff words.  To get shorter than that requires specific information about the options you have on your Settings menu, although if your labels use proportional text, a word like *Limits* may take less room than *Setup*.